# Use iphone as speaker with old unibody white Mac

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, audio, speakers

I have a very old Mac, white Unibody 2009. High Sierra 10.13.6 with upgraded 8GB and SSD.

I also have a iPhone SE.

The speakers on my old Mac are past their best and the volume from my iPhone can get louder. Since my apartment has a lot of street noise I was hoping that I could use my iPhone as a speaker without having to buy a separate speaker.

I found an app 'Airfoil' which, I think, uses Airplay to play sound from one device on another.

While trying to stream video with this app on both my phone and my Mac, everything works perfectly except for the lag. There's a 3 to 4 second delay from what I see visually on my Mac and what I hear via my iPhone.

I wondered if there are any alternative solutions, perhaps by having my iphone plugged in with a USB?

Comment: By plugging it on the USB I know you can use the iPhone as a Microphone, but I don't know about as a Speaker. To setup it as a Mic, you have to configure it under "Audio MIDI Setup" app. Click Launchpad -> Utilities -> Audio MIDI Setup. IF (if something exists) to configure it as a Speaker, it will be configurable using that App. I never tried [as speaker], but you can take a look there and check if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I took a look at Audio MIDI Setup utility after plugging in my iPhone with a USB cable. My phone appeared as a device and I clicked 'enable' then saw this message 'In this mode, your iPhone or iPad will appear as an audio INPUT device on your Mac, enabling the recording of non-telephony audio via the USB cable'. So it looks like this won't work as an audio output, only input. Thanks all the same.